# c++ rogue game, creating the map, need an idea

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a game, with graphics represented as characters. I am working on a class which will provide a map. I am at the point where program successfully makes random amount of rooms with random placement, and now, I need to make corridors that will connect these rooms together.

Please keep in mind that I am new to this, and if my code looks stupid remember that this is all I could do with the knowledge I have :).

Basically at this point, I am not sure how to approach the problem of creating rooms together trough corridors, and I could really use an idea.

Here is the code that I wrote.

Note: randInt(int argument) is just a function I use somewhere else and it returns
a number between 0 and argument-1.

Dungeon.h file--------------------

```
#ifndef DUNGEON_H
#define DUNGEON_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "utilities.h"
using namespace std;



struct Room
{
    int leftUpPosition_row;
    int leftUpPosition_col;
    int length;
    int heigth;
};



class Dungeon
{

public:
    Dungeon();
    ~Dungeon();
    void display(string msg) const;
    void testDisplay(int whichOne) const;

private:
    vector<Room> m_rooms;
    int m_numOfRooms;
};

#endif
```

Dungeon.cpp file--------------------

```
    #include "Dungeon.h"



    Dungeon::Dungeon()
    {

        m_numOfRooms=4+randInt(3);
//Note that randInt(3) is just a function I use somewhere else and it returns
//a number between 0 and argument-1.


        cout<<"Max rooms is: "<<m_numOfRooms<<endl;

        bool stop=false;

        int roomsCreated=0;

        for(int i=0;i<m_numOfRooms && stop==false  ;i++)
        {

            m_rooms.push_back(Room());
            m_rooms[i].heigth=3+randInt(6);
            m_rooms[i].length=6+randInt(13);

            //Creating the first room
            if(i==0)
            {
                m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_row=1+randInt(16-m_rooms[i].heigth);
                m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_col=1+randInt(68-m_rooms[i].length);

                roomsCreated++;
            }
            else   //Creating the rooms that are not the first.
            {

                int attemptingToCreateRoom=0;
                bool goodPos=false;
                bool goon=true;

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                while(goodPos==false)
                {
                    goon=true;

                    m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_row=1+randInt(16-m_rooms[i].heigth);
                    m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_col=1+randInt(68-m_rooms[i].length);


                    for(int k=0;k<roomsCreated && goon==true;) //Compares with created rooms to make sure that they do not overlap

                    {

                        if(  (m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_row + m_rooms[i].heigth) < (m_rooms[k].leftUpPosition_row) || (m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_row) > (m_rooms[k].leftUpPosition_row+ m_rooms[k].heigth)  || (m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_col + m_rooms[i].length) < (m_rooms[k].leftUpPosition_col) || (m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_col) > (m_rooms[k].leftUpPosition_col+ m_rooms[k].length))
                        {
                            k++;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goon=false;
                        }

                    }

                    if(goon ==true)
                    {
                        roomsCreated++;
                        goodPos=true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        attemptingToCreateRoom++;

                        if(attemptingToCreateRoom ==100000)
                        {
                            m_rooms.pop_back();
                            roomsCreated--;
                            i--;
                            stop=true;
                            break;


                        }
                    }
                }

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            }

            cout<<"Rooms Created So Far: "<<roomsCreated<<endl;

        }

        m_numOfRooms=roomsCreated;

    }



    void Dungeon::display(string msg) const
    {


        char grid[17][69];
        int r,c;

        for (r = 0; r < 17; r++)
            for (c = 0; c < 69; c++)
            {
                grid[r][c]='#';
            }

            for(int i=0;i<m_numOfRooms;i++)
            {


                for (r =m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_row ; r < m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_row+m_rooms[i].heigth; r++)
                    for (c = m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_col; c < m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_col+m_rooms[i].length; c++)
                    {
                        grid[r][c]=' ';
                    }



            }

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            for(int i=0;i<m_numOfRooms;i++)
            {
                r =m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_row;
                c = m_rooms[i].leftUpPosition_col;

                grid[r][c]=(char) i+49;



            }


            /////////////////////////////////////////////////


            for (r = 0; r < 17; r++)
            {
                for (c = 0; c < 69; c++)
                    cout << grid[r][c];
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;

    }
```

Here is how my output looks like right now

[image: Here is how my output looks like right now]
Here is how completed game with corridors will look like

[image: Here is how completed program with corridors will look like]

Answer (score 0):

As far as general rogue development, you should really check out RogueBasin if you haven't already.  There are a lot of resources there to get you pointed in the right direction.  Try this [FAQ](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Roguelike_Dev_FAQ#How_do_you_make_sure_all_your_rooms_and_passages_are_reachable.3F) for starters -- it addresses a few room issues, along with many other topics.

There are libraries available that do the screen drawing for you if you want to spend your time focusing on other aspects of the game.  They abstract the screen a bit so that you can just say where you want to print a character, and let them take care of things like console modes, control characters, etc.  That way you can concentrate on WHAT you want to print without having to deal with the low level details.

On the Unix/Linux side I'd got with something like ncurses.  There aren't as many options on Windows, but it looks like [PDCurses](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pdcurses.htm) is an option.